# How to check if elements of macro are in another macro

Tags: string, unique, stata

I have a simple-seeming problem, but in practice it seems to be more involved. In python, for example, it seems like it would be much more straightforward. But I would really like to learn how to do this in Stata.

Say that I have a big dataset. I have several string variables, `S1`, `S2`, and `S3`. I get a subset of `S1` based on some criteria. Let's say that this gets me (after sorting and only the data of interest are displayed):

```
    S1
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
5   E
```

Based on different criteria, I get, for `S2`:

```
    S2
1   B
2   B
3   C
4   F
```

For `S3`:

```
    S3
1   B
2   Long string
```

What I am interested in doing is to get a list of all of the distinct values across `S1`, `S2`, and `S3`. One way I have thought about doing this is:

1. Save all desired values of `S1` into a macro, `M1`. I didn't figure out how one is able to do this.
2. Save all desired values of `S2` into a macro, `M2`.
3. Check if the values of `M2` are in `M1`. Do not add the values of `M2` to `M1` that are already in `M1`, but do add the values of `M2` to `M1` that are not already there. It seems like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456229/comparing-elements-of-two-different-local-macros-in-stata) is similar to how to do this step. (Why is there a `:` in front of `list`?)
4. Repeat step 3, except for `S3`/`M3` instead of `S2`/`M2`.

This would produce the macro `M1` with values:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   Long String
```

Note that I do not need this to be in a macro. If it could be in a matrix or some other way, that would work as well. The important part is to get the information.

Comment: Have you read the documentation at `help macrolists`?

Comment: Despite your last paragraph, it does make a difference how you want this to be represented. If your real problem is as small as your examples imply, macro manipulation is the tool of choice, and you could do worse than start with `levelsof`. If you have a big problem and/or you want to do things downstream with the distinct values as data, dataset manipulation centred on reducing datasets and then applying a `merge` may well be the quite different route to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several ways to do this.

Many assumptions made in this example (many things are not clear in your post):

```
clear
set more off

input ///
str15(s1 s2 s3)
a "b" "b"
b "b" "long string"
c "c" ""
d "f" ""
e "" ""
end

list

stack s*, into(news) clear
bysort news : keep if _n == 1

drop _stack
list
```

If you want to work your way through, using macros, then `help macrolists` and `help levelsof` can aid:

```
clear
set more off

input ///
str15(s1 s2 s3)
a "b" "b"
b "b" "long string"
c "c" ""
d "f" ""
e "" ""
end

list

local uvalues
foreach var of varlist _all {
    levelsof `var', local(loc`var')
    local uvalues : list uvalues | loc`var'
}

display `"`uvalues'"'
```

Saying more about how your variables are organized (e.g. one or several files), whether you care or not to destroy the original data set, the treatment of missings, etc. can probably get you an ad hoc answer.

Comment: I don't care if I destroy the original data set. I was able to modify the code you provided to get the exact solution I needed. Thanks!